# PHP how to arrange array key values based on date

Tags: php, arrays, date, foreach, php-7

I want to arrange array key of value based on array value date ( from - to ) , for example following is my array and I want to arrange booking date from this array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56
            [user_id] => 12
            [name] => A
            [email] => hhjhj@df.com
            [phone] => 4522111111
            [service_name] => a:1:{i:0;s:14:"Beard modeling";}
            [booking_date] => 2021-01-01
            [time] => 18:30:00
            [barbar_id] => 11
            [created_date] => 2021-01-01 12:11:35
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 57
            [user_id] => 12
            [name] => B
            [email] => hhjhj@df.com
            [phone] => 4522111111
            [service_name] => a:1:{i:0;s:14:"Beard modeling";}
            [booking_date] => 2021-01-09
            [time] => 18:30:00
            [barbar_id] => 11
            [created_date] => 2021-01-01 12:11:35
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [user_id] => 12
            [name] => C
            [email] => hhjhj@df.com
            [phone] => 4522111111
            [service_name] => a:1:{i:0;s:14:"Beard modeling";}
            [booking_date] => 2021-01-14
            [time] => 18:30:00
            [barbar_id] => 11
            [created_date] => 2021-01-01 12:11:35
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 61
            [user_id] => 12
            [name] => GGG
            [email] => d@fdfdf.com
            [phone] => 4522111111
            [service_name] => a:1:{i:0;s:14:"Beard modeling";}
            [booking_date] => 2021-01-17
            [time] => 18:30:00
            [barbar_id] => 11
            [created_date] => 2021-01-01 12:11:35
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59
            [user_id] => 12
            [name] => k
            [email] => hhjhj@df.com
            [phone] => 4522111111
            [service_name] => a:1:{i:0;s:14:"Beard modeling";}
            [booking_date] => 2021-01-28
            [time] => 18:30:00
            [barbar_id] => 11
            [created_date] => 2021-01-01 12:11:35
        )

)
```

I want to arrange **booking_date** like

```
booking_date :  2021-01-01 To 2021-01-09
booking_date :  2021-01-14 To 2021-01-17
booking_date :  2021-01-17 To 2021-01-28
```

I have tried below the code but it's not considered booking_date :  2021-01-28

```
foreach ($getUsers as $kt=> $value) {    
    if($kt % 2 ==0){
        echo "booking_date".$getUsers[$kt]['booking_date'].'</br>';  



        $from = $getUsers[$kt]['booking_date'];
    }else{
       echo "booking_date ELSE".$getUsers[$kt]['booking_date'].'</br>';  
      // echo "EEE".$sql.'</br>';  

      $to =$from.' To ' .$getUsers[$kt]['booking_date'];

     }
}
```

Someone please help me, What I have to change in my script?

Comment: What exactly is the logic behind your expected output? You have 5 elements in your array, but your output shows 6 of them. How should the program know which element is to be used twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your original question where you want an output of:

```
booking_date :  2021-01-01 To 2021-01-09
booking_date :  2021-01-14 To 2021-01-17
booking_date :  2021-01-17 To 2021-01-28
```

I think [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) would be convenient, given you are pairing items together to create a 'from' and 'to'.

The other part of the solution is just to keep track of the 2nd last `booking_date`, so we can use it as the `from` for the last element.

I added in handling for an array with only 1 element as well, as I'm not really sure of your use case.

```
 <?php

    $userBookings = [
         0 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-01' ],
         1 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-09' ],
         2 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-14' ],
         3 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-17' ],
         4 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-28' ]
    ];

    $userBookingsPairs = array_chunk($userBookings, 2);

    $fromDate = $toDate = $previousToDate = '';

    foreach ($userBookingsPairs as $userBookingsChunk) {
            $isPair = count($userBookingsChunk) === 2;

            if ($isPair) {
                    $from = reset($userBookingsChunk);
                    $to = end($userBookingsChunk);
                    $fromDate = $from['booking_date'];
                    $previousToDate = $toDate = $to['booking_date'];
            } elseif (!empty($previousToDate)) {
                    // Last element following pairs
                    $to = reset($userBookingsChunk);
                    $fromDate = $previousToDate;
                    $toDate = $to['booking_date'];
            } else {
                    // Single element only
                    $to = reset($userBookingsChunk);
                    $toDate = $to['booking_date'];
                    echo "booking_date: {$toDate}<br>";
                    break;
            }

            echo "booking_date: {$fromDate} To {$toDate}<br>";
    }
```

As for your **second question**:

`2021-01-01 To 2021-01-09 , 2021-01-09 To 2021-01-14 , 2021-01-14 To 2021-01-17 And 2021-01-17 To 2021-01-28`

So in basic terms, for the first 2 elements, we take the `booking_date` from element #1 and element #2 and combine them.

For the next 2 elements, we combine the `booking_date` of element #2 with element #3, then element #3 with element #4. So on and so forth until the last element, where we combine element #n-1 with element #n.

```
 <?php

      $userBookings = [
         0 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-01' ],
         1 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-09' ],
         2 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-14' ],
         3 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-17' ],
         4 => [ 'booking_date' => '2021-01-28' ]
      ];

      $output = '';

      $userBookingsPairs = array_chunk($userBookings, 2);

      $fromDate = $toDate = $previousFromDate = $previousToDate = '';

      foreach ($userBookingsPairs as $userBookingsChunk) {
           $isPair = count($userBookingsChunk) === 2;

           if ($isPair) {
                $from = reset($userBookingsChunk);
                $to = end($userBookingsChunk);
                $fromDate = $from['booking_date'];
                $toDate = $to['booking_date'];
                if (empty($previousFromDate)) {
                     // First iteration
                     $output = "$fromDate To $toDate";
                } else { // 'n'th iteration
                     // print date range using prior element
                     $output .= ", $previousToDate To $fromDate";

                     // print date range for this element
                     $output .= ", $fromDate To $toDate";
                }

                $previousFromDate = $fromDate;
                $previousToDate = $toDate;
           } elseif (!empty($previousToDate)) {
                // Last element following pairs
                $to = reset($userBookingsChunk);
                $output .= ", $previousToDate To {$to['booking_date']}";
           } else {
                // Single element only
                $to = reset($userBookingsChunk);
                $output = $to['booking_date'];
           }
      }

      echo $output;
```

Comment: Still it's not given last date from 2021-01-17 to 2021-01-28

Comment: True, updated to reflect that part of the question, closer?

Comment: nope, still last give booking_date: 2021-01-17 To 2021-01-17 not showing 28

Comment: hey , Is it possible to list like 2021-01-01 To 2021-01-09  , 2021-01-09 To  2021-01-14 , 2021-01-14  To 2021-01-17 And 2021-01-17 To 2021-01-28

Comment: @RohanVarma it is Rohan, instead of using `echo` immediately, you could store the result in a variable (first defined before the `foreach` loop), and then print it after the `foreach` loop. I would hope that if I addressed your original question you would accept it. You should have a close enough solution to get there. I'm happy to answer these follow up questions though.

Comment: YEs, I'll accept , Can you please update this answer so I can easily understand

Comment: How can i get this output,  2021-01-01 To 2021-01-09 , 2021-01-09 To 2021-01-14 , 2021-01-14 To 2021-01-17 And 2021-01-17 To 2021-01-28

Comment: I've answered 2 separate questions. The most recent one I answered has a very similar output to your 3rd question. The comments section is not the place to ask for all kinds of variations - it is expected you would use the answer and tweak it to however you need. If the remaining scope is legitimately too difficult after you've attempted, raise a separate question, show us how close you get and what the issue is, and we can try and help from there. It seems a bit unfair to keep asking me to make small tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($getUsers);$i+2) {  
    if(isset($getUsers[$i]))
        echo "booking_date: ".$getUsers[$i]['booking_date'].'-'.$getUsers[$i+1]['booking_date'].'</br>';  

    }
}
```

Comment: `$i+2` creates an infinite loop :)

Comment: What? You have a limit, you dont create any infinite loop when you change the increment. This solution seems pretty good.

Comment: @Ahmad provided a good solution for every element except the last (it's checking beyond the bounds of the array by `1` at the end). Re; the infinite loop, the `$i+2` isn't incrementing, it's adding `2` to `$i` and not incrementing the value of `$i` (run the code to confirm).

Comment: How can i get this output, 2021-01-01 To 2021-01-09 , 2021-01-09 To 2021-01-14 , 2021-01-14 To 2021-01-17 And 2021-01-17 To 2021-01-28

Answer (score 0):

Use a for bucle, with an increment of 2. Create the interval with "index" - "index+1".

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use this code:

```
        foreach ($array as $kt => $value) {

        if ($kt % 2 !== 0) {
            continue;
        }

        $to = null;
        if(isset($array[$kt + 1])) {
            $to = ' To ' .$array[$kt + 1]['booking_date'];
        }

        echo 'booking_date: ' . $value['booking_date'] . $to . '<br>';
    }
```

Comment: Not work and also not given output that I explained in my queastion.

Comment: Not given result of last date  from 2021-01-17 to 2021-01-28

Comment: because the even key of the array is assumed to be "from" and the even key is "to"

Comment: So how your can I get result as I want, I tried your but not given result that I want